# Getting image from Class Library

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am doing a refactor of my Xamarin project, in which I want to build nuget-packages for my platform specific projects.
And since you can't make your "App.Droid", "App.iOS" and "App.UWP" into nugets I am using class libraries for this.

My problem is when I put my images (ordinary *.png-files) in my UWP-class library it won't work. It is working in both iOS and Android.
So my question is if anyone knows if this is possible, and if so how?

My current setup is as follows:

My UWP-project is named "App.UWP". This is the project i build and the project has the "App.xaml" and "MainPage.xaml".
I then created a "Class library (Universal Windows)" named "Company.Mobile.Core.UWP".

My "App.UWP" is referencing "Company.Mobile.Core.UWP".

I know I have a working connection between the two. My Custom renderers are in the "Company.Mobile.Core.UWP"-project and not in "App.UWP" and is working fine.

Cheers,
Tobias

Comment: Do you mean that you put the picture resources in the class library and then use it in the portable library?

Comment: Exactly :)
So my picture "background.png" for example. It is in the class library, but is not found in the portable library.
So when i run my application as UWP, background is white (since it cannot find background.png)

If i put the picture in the portable library (in the same hierarchy) the background picture is shown.

Comment: I have tried to put the picture in the class library, and use it with this ( `Source="Company.Mobile.Core.UWP/timg.jpg"`), it works in my side. Could you show more detail ?

Comment: Writing the Source with the full path does work. However, this breaks the path for Android och iOS. And if possible, I would like to have the same path for all projects. And not three different paths dependning on the platform. I would like the name of the picture only. Like ```Source="background.png"```

Comment: Yep, the path you mentioed is [`Local Images`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Local_Images) for each platform.

Comment: Do you mean that the class library picture resourse has the same feature?

Comment: For your requirement, you could use [`Embedded Images`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Embedded_Images) to match each platform

Comment: "Do you mean that the class library picture resourse has the same feature?". Yes. I want to have my images in the Class Library. And in my code i want to have ```Source="background.png"``` and NOT ```Source="Class library\background.png"```. It is working on Android and iOS but not UWP

Comment: `It is working on Android and iOS but not UWP` ? Does each client project  have a class library? Such as `ClassLibrary.IOS, ClassLibrary.Android`.

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention that :)

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?